# Force exception to be raised when setting invalid field on model instance

Tags: django, django-1.10

If I accidentally typo the field name on a model, I want to raise an exception rather than silently failing:

```
obj = MyModel()
obj.fieldsdoesnotexist = 'test' # No exception is raised
```

How can I make Django raise exceptions when setting invalid fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating Mixin that overrides setattr behavior like this:

```
class ValidateFieldNamesMixin:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not hasattr(self, name):
            raise ValueError('Invalid field name!')
        return super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

And you must inherit this mixin in your MyModel class:

```
class MyModel(ValidateFieldNamesMixin, Model):
    # etc
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it allows me to set the invalid field in the first place?

Comment: It's normal python behavior that you can set new attribute/method to your class. So if you want to change it you must override setattr.